# no devuelve nada la funcion leer archivo nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs

la funcion leer archivo no devuelve nada, pero si muestra por consola

```
function leer(archivo){ 
    fs.readFile('./archivos/'+archivo, 'utf8',
        function(err, data) {

                return data;  
        }
    ); 
};
```

cuando lo uso desde otro fichero

```
console.log(escritorLector.leer(files[a]));
```

no muestra nada

Sin embargo, por consola se muestra bien (en el mismo archivo).

```
function leer(archivo){ 
    fs.readFile('./archivos/'+archivo, 'utf8',
        function(err, data) {
            console.log(data);
            return data;  
        }
    );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jamás obtendrás una respuesta porque estás devolviendo desde el callback.

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Pasarle un callback a `leer`.
2. Utilizar `fs#readFileSync`.

#### Pasando un callback

```
function leer(path, cb) {
  fs.readFile(`/archivos/${archivo}`, function(err, content) {
    if(err) { /* hacer algo */ }
    cb(content);
  });
}
```

Y lo usarías así:

```
leer('archivo.dat', function(content) {
  console.log(content);
});
```

#### Usar fs#readFileSync

```
function leer(path) {
  return fs.readFileSync(`/archivos/${path}`);
}
```

Y de ésta forma si funcionaría lo que pretendes:

```
console.log(leer('archivo.dat'));
```